# Unittest python не могу понять как проверить что функция что-то возвращает

Tags: python, юнит-тесты, python-unittest

К примеру я хочу проверить возвращает ли функция returning переменную x после срабатывания условия

Вот код

```
    def test_function(self):
        x = 5
        y = True
        def returning():
            if y == True:
                pass
        self.assertEqual(5, x)
```

Comment: если нужно проверить функцию, то и нужно в ассерте вызывать функцию

Comment: у меня в проекте функция на много больше и проверить мне надо только то что после условия функция вызывает переменную

Comment: Чтоб проверить, что функция что-то делает в каких-то условиях, нужно функцию вызвать в этих условиях. Другого пути нет

Comment: что такое "функция вызывает переменную"? Вызывает или возвращает?

Comment: возвращает оговорка

Comment: Коротко - никак не проверить, функции не возвращают переменные, они возвращают значения. Проверить что значение взято из конкретной переменной фактически не возможно.